# Is there a way to filter out Minecraft questions?

Tags: discussion

The front page is littered with Minecraft questions and I kinda want to see other video game questions on the front page.

Is there a way to filter out Minecraft questions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore tags. This will hide them from the front page, search etc. Go to [Your tag preferences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/me) to add ignored tags.

Comment: Yaay thank you!

Comment: Make sure the radio button is set to 'Hide questions in your ignored tags' as well

Comment: On a somewhat related note: I hope that the SE Android app gets the ability to filter based on your tag preferences soon. The app is pretty useless to me until that happens, specifically because it's such a chore to slog through all the Minecraft questions. I've sent feedback e-mails through the Play store but never heard anything.

Comment: @UnknownZombie - might be worth raising on Meta.SE

Comment: @UnknownZombie that feature request [already exists on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244196/update-the-android-app-to-hide-questions-under-ignored-tags-when-i-have-that-se)

Comment: Dont forget to also ignore minecraft-* to get rid of all the subtags for minecraft.

Comment: It's almost as if minecraft deserves it's own SE site. I think that it would be littered with all questions and no answers though... :)

Comment: @TimS. I remember trying to do that on Area51, but it got closed because it would take people away from Arqade.

Comment: @Peanut That seems like a silly reason since there is both StackOverflow _and_ Programmers.SE. I'd also argue there's a lot of crossover between SuperUser and Unix.SE, but all of those examples are highly successful on their own, despite being derivatives, because they are highly popular individual subjects. Arqade isn't going to die just because anyone who has a question about Minecraft goes to a different SE to ask about it. (This isn't directed _at_ you, it's just a response)

Comment: @Troyen `minecraft*` would be better.

Answer (score 9):

Do note however that you have quick access to your favorite and ignored tags when you're on the main homepage.  Click on the `edit` link next to your favorite tags.

[image: the edit link]

Then you'd be able to add/remove tags from your favorites and your ignored tags.

[image: expanded]

Add `minecraft` to have the site put less emphasis on questions with the tag both in the UI and in the algorithms that give you questions to look at.  To be more inclusive of more minecrafty tags, add `minecraft*` (with a `*`).  You can even remove questions completely if you change your tag preferences to "Hide questions in your ignored tags."

[image: tag preferences]

Comment: +1 as its better explained than the accepted answer (which is just a link to the preferences)

Comment: Which was all I needed

Comment: @bmarkham This answer is more complete and more useful to future users who might have the same question. I've already blocked minecraft tags, but the ability to use a wildcard was something I was not aware of. You've accepted a "good enough" answer, and that's your right, but this really is the _better_ answer.

Comment: +1 for helping locate the ignore questions radio button... why isn't that also in account tag settings?